# powershell output to CSV

Tags: powershell-4.0

I would like the output of this powershell to be sent to file, currently it outputs to screen, I have tried adding various pipe to file commands but it populates the file with numbers and the original content from the screen

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=Group)(|(groupType=2)(groupType=4)(groupType=8)))"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn") | Out-Null
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member") | Out-Null

$($colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
foreach ($objResult in $colResults){
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties;
    Write-Output $objItem.cn
    foreach ($objMember in $objItem.member) {
        Write-Output "   $objMember" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Use StreamWriter instead of Write-Output, there are many examples. P.S. `$($colResults` makes no sense, probably a copypaste error.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I am not very proficient at powershell, could you please send some code that would achieve my request?

Comment: Hi, still do not have any output, the script works fine to the console, just cannot get it to dump to file